# How do I make my RoR's links absolute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`<%= link_to 'Show', buddy, :only_path => false %>`

Doesn't seem to work.  I need the full path: http://www.my-server.com/buddy

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've defined buddy as a resource in your routes.rb:

```
map.resources :buddy
```

then you should be able to do the following:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', buddy_url(buddy) %>
```